# Windows 10 with nvidia gtx 710

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, hdr

Hi I  have skyworth 4k TV bt I can't enable hdr on windows 10, I'm using nvidia 710 graphics card with 2gb.when I play movies with powerdvd19 it does say my TV support hdr so I must turn it on. What is the solution?

Comment: BTW does HDR10 really have noticable improvement compared with 8bit? Especially If your media don't have very high bit rate like 200Mbps+?

Comment: Unfortunately support for TVs is off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the Nvidia GT 710 does not support HDR over HDMI. The HDMI revision is only 1.4, and needs to be HDMI 2.0a to support HDR.

Also, this graphics card will struggle with 4k playback, or also 1080P 60fps. I suggest getting a low cost GT 1030 instead if you want an HDR, HEVC and HDMI 2.0 enabled video card. Depending on your location and computer, an RX 570/580 may be a cheaper option if you have a desktop.